# C# deployment project: Icon doesn't appear for the extension associated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

> **Linking Icon to an Extension doesn't create default icon path in registry.**

In Demo C# Deployment Project Suppose we have an **Extensions "abc"** and an **Icon "abc.ico"** to be associated with it. Icon is placed in **File System** of the deployment proj. Extension abc is defined in **File Types** and icon is associated with it.

> **But in registry the default icon path is empty and the exe for the icon is not generated.** 
>   If Default Icon Path is not created the icon will not be visible.

Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: I have post a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JSZUE.png), if you have set the `Command`, `Icon`, `Extension` for the file type, it should work. Check if you missed something

Comment: Thanks @kennyzx. I had already set the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it opening the `Visual Studio as Administrator` solves the problem.